# CakePHP 3 Plugin CsvView.csv, export with many relations

Tags: cakephp, export-to-csv

Specifically, I am using the ViewCsv plugin, this plugin to export a json to csv requires a flat array to be passed to it, but I can't figure out how to make INNER relelations flat. In my code i have a contain with ['Users', 'Resources', etc].

```
public function export()
{
    $bookings = $this->Bookings->find('index')->contain(['Users', 'Resources', 'Customers', 'Unavailabilities']);
    $_delimiter = chr(9); //tab
    $_bom = true;
    $_null = 'null';

    $_header = $this->Bookings->getSchema()->columns();
    unset($_header[9], $_header[11], $_header[12], $_header[13]);
    $_extract = $this->Bookings->getSchema()->columns();
    unset($_extract[9], $_extract[11], $_extract[12], $_extract[13])
    $this->setResponse($this->getResponse()->withDownload('BookingsExport.csv'));

    $this->viewBuilder()->setClassName('CsvView.Csv');
    $this->set('_serialize', true);
    $this->set(compact('bookings', '_header', '_extract', '_delimiter', '_null', '_bom'));
}
```

I need to get the tables that are inside the contain inside the csv file. At this time i get only the Bookings table inside.

Comment: $bookings doesn‘t contain any of the specified entities from your contain(). I think you have to convert the associated entities by yourself to a flat structure before passing them to the view.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Maybe i can do a query for each table of the contain that are related to bookings and set manually as flat array.